# PT/PST was not taken on 20.04 as valid timezone

Tags: timezone

Used the following command to change timezone on 20.04:

```
 sudo timedatctl set-timezone PST  //PT has same error
```

But receiving error of invalid time zone or missing (strange!).

Did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install pst-utils
```

But the error is the same. What is the right way to install pacific time?

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo timedatectl set-timezone US/Pacific`

- The `pst-utils` package has nothing to do with timezones. It's about working with Microsoft Outlook PST files. You can safely uninstall it.